# Running raw_input on a pygtk application

Tags: python, pygtk

I need to make a graphical application that reads data from the console to update some widgets, this will have to do with 2 threads, one for the GUI and one for the console. The problem is that raw_input function does not work and also freezes the application. Here is the code.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import gobject
from time import sleep
import sys
import threading

class Worker (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, app):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.app = app

    def run(self):
        text = raw_input("Enter some text: ") #It freezes the application
        #text = "Hola" #It Works
        self.app.writeMessage(text, False)

class Application:
    def __init__(self, title, xPos, yPos):
        gtk.threads_init()
        self.win = gtk.Window()
        screen = self.win.get_screen()
        screenW = screen.get_width()
        screenH = screen.get_height()
        windowW = int(screenW * 0.5)
        windowH = int(screenH * 0.25)
        if type(xPos) is float:
            xPos = int(screenW * xPos)
        if type(yPos) is float:
            yPos = int(screenH * yPos)

        self.messageArea = gtk.TextView()
        self.scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scroll.add(self.messageArea)
        self.win.set_size_request(windowW, windowH)
        self.win.set_title(title)
        self.win.add(self.scroll)
        self.win.show_all()
        self.win.move(xPos, yPos)
        self.win.connect("destroy", gtk.mainquit)


    def doOperation(self, function, *args, **kw):
        def idle_func():
            try:
                gtk.threads_enter()
                function(*args, **kw)
                return False
            finally:
                gtk.threads_leave()
        gobject.idle_add(idle_func)

    def sleeper():
        time.sleep(.001)
        return 1 # don't forget this otherwise the timeout will be removed

    def mainloop(self):
        #Trick for running threads and pygtk on win32 enviroment
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            gtk.timeout_add(400, self.sleeper)
        gtk.threads_enter()
        gtk.mainloop()
        gtk.threads_leave()


    def writeMessage(self, message, isMainThread):
        if isMainThread:
            buf = self.messageArea.get_buffer()
            end_iter = buf.get_end_iter()
            buf.insert(end_iter, message)
        else:           
            self.doOperation(self.writeMessage, message, True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application("Hello", 0, 0)
    worker = Worker(app)
    app.doOperation(worker.start)
    app.mainloop()
```

Curiously the code only works if you run it in eclipse pydev, but it doesn't is the intention, I must run it from console. So this is the question, how to execute raw_input function and GUI on separate threads?

Answer (score 0):

[take a look at this](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2010-June/018738.html).It explains about absence of event loop support in python and you can disable pygtk event loop after importing it.

Comment: That works for me, but I do not know if I'm doing it correctly. I just added the line "gtk.set_interactive (False)" at the beginning of the code and I test the program in both, windows and linux operating system. Sorry for the english, I only speak spanish